# Confusion about Lemma 4.2.1 of Diestel.

Tags: graph-theory

In Diestel's "Graph Theory" Chapter 4 on Planar Graphs we have the following Lemma:

> **Lemma 4.2.1.** Let $G$ be a plane graph, $f \in F(G)$ a face, and $H\subseteq G$ a subgraph.
>
> (i) $H$ has a face $f'$ containing $f$.
>
> (ii) If the frontier of $f$ lies in $H$, then $f'= f$.

The proof Diestel gives for (i) makes sense to me. For (ii) I believe I understand intuitively what is going on but I do not understand the argument being made by Diestel:

> *[Proof]* (ii) Recall from Section 4.1 that any arc between $f$ and $f'\smallsetminus f$ meets the frontier $X$ of $f$. If $f' \smallsetminus f \neq \varnothing$ then there is such an arc inside $f'$, whose points in $X$ do not lie in $H$. Hence $X \not\subseteq H$.

I certainly agree that any arc between $f$ and $f' \smallsetminus f$ meets $X$. (1) Why does $f' \smallsetminus f \neq \varnothing$ imply "there is such an arc inside $f'$"? (2) Why do such points not belong in $H$?

Expanding on (2), if I understand correctly, there is an arc that crosses from $f$ to $f' \smallsetminus f$ and at some point $x \in X$. But by assumption the frontier of $f$ lies in $H$, so I would imagine $x \in X \implies x \in H$. Thus, it does not seem clear to me why $X \not\subseteq H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to rephrase the proof.

Assume that $f' \ne f$; let $p$ be a point in $f$ and let $q$ be a point in $f' \smallsetminus f$. Because $p,q$ are both in $f'$, there is an arc from $p$ to $q$ entirely contained in $f'$. At some point, this arc crosses the frontier of $f$ (since it leaves $f$) but it never crosses the frontier of $f'$. So the crossing point is a point $x$ on the frontier of $f$, but not of $f'$.

Since $x \in f'$, in particular $x \in \mathbb R^2 \smallsetminus H$, because $f'$ is a connected region of $\mathbb R^2 \smallsetminus H$; in other words, $x \notin H$. However, $x$ is on the frontier of $f$, by construction. Therefore, it is not the case that the frontier of $f$ lies in $H$: we've found a point of the frontier of $f$ which does not!

Therefore if the frontier of $f$ *does* lie in $H$, then we must have $f' = f$, or else the argument above leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Ok, so the key that I think I was missing is $x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \smallsetminus H \implies x \notin H$ by complementation. So, when Diestel uses things like "meets" I need to be careful if he is talking about a realization of $H$ or $\mathbb{R}^2 \smallsetminus H$. Thanks.